# Cursor drag preview similar to web browser?

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, mouse-cursor

After playing around with the DragDrop feature, I learn that I could update and use my own custom cursor during the Drag operation through the `GiveFeedback` event.

Within the `GiveFeedback` I create an image and then set the cursor to that image.

```
    Private Sub Form1_GiveFeedback(sender As Object, e As GiveFeedbackEventArgs) Handles Form1.GiveFeedback
        e.UseDefaultCursors = False
        Dim pb As New PictureBox
        pb.Size = New Drawing.Size(100, 100)
        pb.Image = TextToImage("My Text")
        pb.BackColor = Color.LightGray

        Dim myPic As New Bitmap(pb.Image)
        Cursor.Current = New Cursor(CType(myPic, Bitmap).GetHicon())
    End Sub
```

The issue with this is that the cursor now becomes just the image so you can't really tell where your actual cursor is at, it becomes harder to drop the item accurately onto another control.

How do I do something like when you copy text/images in a web browser where it has a preview of what you're dragging?

For example: When I drag highlighted text and images, the drag has a preview of the content AND the cursor changes to show if the content can be dropped.

[image]